# How to get state from a component to navigationOptions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

Is there any way of getting something like shown below?

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  ...
  const [state, setState] = useState('test');
  ...
}

App.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
  headerRight: <Text>{i want the state value in here}</Text>,
});
```

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: You are declaring ```navigationOptions``` like a static function of your function/component App. If you don't instantiate your component how can you get the state?

Comment: The way above is the proper way of declaring the ```navigationOptions``` based on the official documentation and it works fine. I found the answer to my question. I had to do ```navigatiion.setParams({ item: 'this' })``` and in my ```navigationOptions``` ```screenProps.navigation.getParam('item')```